Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file or assembly "System.Private.CoreLib" could not be found in custom generated assmbly
I use .NET 9 to create a .NET assembly/program programatically via the new emit api.
My test code looks like the following:
PersistedAssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = new(new AssemblyName("HelloWorldTest"), typeof(object).Assembly);
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("HelloWorldTest").DefineType("HelloWorldTest", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);

MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(void), [typeof(string[])]);

ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();

Assembly loadedAssembly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(typeof(Console).Assembly.Location);

ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, World!");
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, loadedAssembly.GetType("System.Console").GetMethod("WriteLine", [typeof(string)]));
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

typeBuilder.CreateType();

MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = assemblyBuilder.GenerateMetadata(out BlobBuilder ilStream, out BlobBuilder fieldData);
PEHeaderBuilder peHeaderBuilder = new(imageCharacteristics: Characteristics.ExecutableImage);

ManagedPEBuilder peBuilder = new(
                header: peHeaderBuilder,
                metadataRootBuilder: new MetadataRootBuilder(metadataBuilder),
                ilStream: ilStream,
                mappedFieldData: fieldData,
                entryPoint: MetadataTokens.MethodDefinitionHandle(methodBuilder.MetadataToken));

BlobBuilder peBlob = new();
peBuilder.Serialize(peBlob);
using FileStream fileStream = new("HelloWorldTest.exe", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
peBlob.WriteContentTo(fileStream);


Upon execution of HelloWorldTest.exe I get the following error:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file or assembly “System.Private.CoreLib, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e” or one of its dependencies was not found. The system cannot find the specified file.

How do I reference this assembly correctly. Or how do I get rid of the error.

I see you’ve opened an issue in the dotnet/runtime repo. As one of the replies explains, PersistedAssemblyBuilder only generates a cross-platform binary, which can’t be executed directly:

.NET Core managed assemblies are not directly executable. .NET Core does not have the integration with the OS loader to enable that. You have to launch the managed assembly using a native binary. For example, dotnet MyAssembly.exe.

Likewise, running dotnet HelloWorldTest.exe will successfully print "Hello, World!".
To create a native executable that executes the cross-platform binary, you can use the HostWriter class from the .NET SDK. This is demonstrated by the sample code below.
You also asked:

For the example you provided I don't really get what refAssembliesPath should be.

On my machine, the reference assembly path for .NET 9.0.0-preview.3 is "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\9.0.0-preview.3.24172.9\ref\net9.0". The sample code below uses the reference assemblies from this directory to avoid taking a dependency on System.Private.CoreLib.

Here’s a complete example that creates a cross-platform binary (HelloWorldTest.dll) using PersistedAssemblyBuilder and a companion native 64-bit Windows executable (HelloWorldTest.exe) using HostWriter:
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection.Metadata;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;
using Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost;

string referencePath = @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\9.0.0-preview.3.24172.9\ref\net9.0";
PathAssemblyResolver resolver = new(Directory.GetFiles(referencePath, "*.dll"));
using MetadataLoadContext context = new(resolver);
Assembly coreAssembly = context.CoreAssembly!;
Type voidType = coreAssembly.GetType(typeof(void).FullName!)!;
Type objectType = coreAssembly.GetType(typeof(object).FullName!)!;
Type stringType = coreAssembly.GetType(typeof(string).FullName!)!;
Type stringArrayType = coreAssembly.GetType(typeof(string[]).FullName!)!;
Type consoleType = coreAssembly.GetType(typeof(Console).FullName!)!;

PersistedAssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = new(new AssemblyName("HelloWorldTest"), coreAssembly);

TypeBuilder typeBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("HelloWorldTest").DefineType("HelloWorldTest", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class, objectType);

MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Main", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, voidType, [stringArrayType]);
ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hello, World!");
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, consoleType.GetMethod("WriteLine", [stringType])!);
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

typeBuilder.CreateType();

MetadataBuilder metadataBuilder = assemblyBuilder.GenerateMetadata(out BlobBuilder ilStream, out BlobBuilder fieldData);
PEHeaderBuilder peHeaderBuilder = new(imageCharacteristics: Characteristics.ExecutableImage);

ManagedPEBuilder peBuilder = new(
    header: peHeaderBuilder,
    metadataRootBuilder: new MetadataRootBuilder(metadataBuilder),
    ilStream: ilStream,
    mappedFieldData: fieldData,
    entryPoint: MetadataTokens.MethodDefinitionHandle(methodBuilder.MetadataToken));

BlobBuilder peBlob = new();
peBuilder.Serialize(peBlob);
using (FileStream fileStream = new("HelloWorldTest.dll", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    peBlob.WriteContentTo(fileStream);
}

HostWriter.CreateAppHost(
    @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Host.win-x64\9.0.0-preview.3.24172.9\runtimes\win-x64\native\apphost.exe",
    "HelloWorldTest.exe",
    "HelloWorldTest.dll");

File.WriteAllText("HelloWorldTest.runtimeconfig.json", @"{
  ""runtimeOptions"": {
    ""tfm"": ""net9.0"",
    ""framework"": {
      ""name"": ""Microsoft.NETCore.App"",
      ""version"": ""9.0.0-preview.3.24172.9""
    }
  }
}");

To access the HostWriter class, you’ll need to add a project reference to Microsoft.NET.HostModel.dll, which on my machine is located at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\9.0.100-preview.3.24204.13".

I think the problem you have is that the .NET Core 9 SDK is not installed in your computer.
You should install it, then try again:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/9.0

If I hadn't installed it, I could not compile the app generating the exe file. I tried reinstalling it, but it did change nothing.

You need to install the SDK and the runtime, else you compile but you cannot run it
